# Задержка отображения в консоли

Tags: javascript

если запустить код в консоли, то до конца работы цикла, `console.log("%o", f[i]);` не будет выводить элемент, почему так происходит и как это можно поправить?

```js
let f = document.querySelectorAll("div")
for (let i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
  console.log("%o", f[i]);
  console.log("----");
  if (confirm("?")) break;
}
```

Comment: Фрейм не блокирует поток с console/log?

Comment: @Алексей но если выводить id фрейма то выводит сразу

Comment: Хотя с любым элементом так

Comment: @JarryRoxwell, результат может зависеть от браузера

Comment: @Grundy, точно, в ff все как надо, а в хроме задержка, выходит это никак не исправить?

Comment: Здесь уже был подобный вопрос, с обновление текста в элементе и alert, не могу найти

Answer (score 0):

```js
let f = document.querySelectorAll("div")
for (let i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
  console.log(f[i].id);
  console.log("----");
  var conf = confirm(`Найден ${i} элемент, продолжить?`)
  if (conf == false) break;

}
```

```html
<div id="id1">1</div>
<div id="id2">2</div>
<div id="id3">3</div>
<div id="id4">4</div>
<div id="id5">5</div>
<div id="id6">6</div>
```

Comment: тогда confurm будет выводиться только один раз и когда все элементы перебраны. И то если выполнить этот код тут на сайте то элементы отобразятся только после диалогового окна

Comment: @JarryRoxwell обновил код, я правильно вас понял?

Comment: да да да, вот так, но с выводом текстовой информации было все в порядке (id, текст, атрибуты), а вот сами элементы отображаются только по завершении цикла `console.log('${f[i].innerText} элемент');` = > `console.log(f[i]`);`